# How/Can I increase the file storage size of my azure shared website?

Tags: azure

I'm pretty content with the speed and database size of the shared website configuration. But I need some more file storage space. This is currently 1gb and I need around 8gb

Cheers

Comment: Just a point of note here - if you do decide to add a blob storage account and reference files (like large videos, images, documents etc.) from that on your website... the container will need to be set as "**Public**".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can increase that (at least for now). What you can do instead is start making use of Blob Storage instead of file storage for your website where you could go much beyond 8 GB.

Answer (score 1):

If you move to Reserved Instance Model then you will get 10 GB storage (shared by all sites). Otherwise I will follow Gaurav, use Blob Storage.